# Get service cloud object data from journey

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a journey with entry of salesforce data and an SMS activity which should contain data coming from service cloud. I have already added the field in entry data but how can I include it in the SMS message? Its not like getting the data from data extension.

Comment: Is the field in the entry source DE if so %%fullfieldname%%

Comment: How can I reference the correct DE in SMS? I think that is possible if the entry is Data Extension, in this scenario, my Entry is salesforce Data

Comment: You reference both the same way.

Comment: You would have to do a lookup() using the %%contactkey%%

Comment: @EazyE you can reference SF Entry Event Fields in the same manner that you have above in an SMS message.

Answer (score 0):

When you set your entry event as SF Data, then a data extension is automatically created with the selected object fields on activation. The process for calling data into an activity is the same across DE and SF entry events. The primary difference in this regard is naming convention, so it's likely you'll need to wrap any calls to retrieve those values with []. i.e. `SET @lead_id = [Contact:Lead:Id]`